# Declaring and initializing TVarRec (array of const) params

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

I want to define a var or const that I can further use in TClientDataSet SetRange method:

```
var
  lRangeStart : array of TVarRec;
  lRangeEnd   : array of TVarRec;

procedure SetRange;
begin

   SetLength (lRangeStart, 2);
   SetLength (lRangeEnd  , 2);

  lRangeStart [0] := Field1; // Incompatible types tVarRect and Integer
  lRangeStart [1] := Field2; // Incompatible types tVarRect and Integer
  lRangeEnd   [0] := Field1; // Incompatible types tVarRect and Integer
  lRangeEnd   [1] := Field2; // Incompatible types tVarRect and Integer

   MyDataSet.SetRange (lRangeStart, lRangeEnd);

end;
```

Comment: Please do not edit your question to beg for help. This is not  *give me help immediately because I need it" site. If you need help urgently, hire a consultant that you can pay enough to devote you their undivided attention. Questions here get answered, but you have to have some patience. :-)

Comment: Ken. My appologies. In fact, I was wondering if I didn't got an answer because my question was too much dummy. Don't worry, I'll be as patient as necessary.

Comment: You edited to add a plea for help after 43 minutes. Sometimes questions here take days (or weeks, or months) to be answered. Expecting help in less than an hour is a little unreasonable. People here donate their time to help others for free; demanding that they do it instantly seems a little inconsiderate. :-)

Comment: Probably the Q had few views because it originally lacked the generic delphi tag, added by RRUZ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not the way it works. You create the arrays differently:

```
MyDataSet.SetRange([Field1, Field2], [Field1, Field2]);
```

The compiler takes care of generating the various `TVarRec` records for you.

You can also have mixed types, if the columns in your index are of different types:

```
MyDataSet.SetRange([1, 'Testing'], [1, 'Testing']);
```

To use input from the user instead, just assign the the user input to variables, doing any necessary type conversions, and pass in the variables.

```
var
  Val1, Val2: Integer;
begin
  Val1 := StrToInt(Edit1.Text);
  Val2 := StrToInt(Edit2.Text);
  MyDataSet.SetRange([Val1, Val2], [Val1, Val2]);
end;
```

Or, you can do the conversion in-line, but exceptions due to invalid types are an issue:

```
MyDataSet.SetRange([StrToInt(Edit1.Text), StrToInt(Edit2.Text)],
                    StrToInt(Edit1.Text), StrToInt(Edit2.Text)]);
```

In order to do so yourself, you'd have to explicitly assign to the appropriate type of each element (which defeats much of the purpose of using an array of const, which is being able to create it on-the-fly in your code and mix types):

```
SetLength(lRangeStart, 2);
lRangeStart[0].vInteger := 1;
lRangeStart[1].vInteger := 2;
```

Comment: Thanks Ken. I want the user to choice the values of the Range. That's why I need to assign this values using a variable.

Comment: You don't need to assign a variable for that, either. You can use user input in the array. I'll edit to show how.